# Account not allowed to suggest edits

Tags: support, suggested-edits, accounts, error-message

I started having this issue recently with editing questions on Stack Overflow (only Stack Overflow, not other stacks where I hang out frequently.)

At the website, I can't even see an "edit" button. At the mobile app, I can see one and get to the editor, but when I click "suggest" I get an error: "Account not allowed to suggest edits".

I think this started around one or two weeks ago, I think first I saw it was when I was about to edit a question and someone else edited it at the same time, so my edit failed, but since then I've been seeing this error.

My reputation is over 1,000 on Stack Overflow. (Not sure I remember correctly, but that's when you get full edit privilege, right?) **UPDATE:** No, full editing privileges are at 2,000. But I should still be able to suggest edits, right?

Anyways, just trying to understand why this is happening and whether I can do any corrective actions on my side to rectify the issue.

**UPDATE:** I seem to have had two rejected edits and four accepted edits (that we can see, some could have been deleted questions?)

Of the two rejected edits, one conflicted with another pending edit (so was rejected because it was a duplicate.)

The other was replacing triple backticks with indentation for a code block. I'm sure if I suggested that, it's because the triple backticks looked wrong to me at the time (I use mobile app mostly.) But looking at that edit on the desktop version, it looks as there's no difference, so it may have been rejected as it was perceived not to fix anything, but I'm sure that would not have been the case...

Am I really in an edit ban because of these two edits that had good intentions?

Comment: You need 2000 reputation for the full edit privilege (1000 on beta sites).

Comment: Thanks @JeanneDark... But I should still be able to suggest edits, right?

Comment: You may have an edit ban in effect, but I'm not sure how to check that.

Comment: You have 4 approved and 2 rejected edits. I'm not sure but this shouldn't be enough for an edit ban.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Yes, I guess that's possible, though I really don't see why I would be banned from editing, I really haven't being abusing that privilege or anything... Wondering if any moderators could take a look?

Comment: @yivi Yes, that's also my suspicion. Btw., I looked at the rejected edits again and one suggested edit conflicted with a subsequent edit and wouldn't count.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a review ban. if there's a pending edit, the edit button is hidden for <2k users. It's also hidden on mobile for all users regardless of rep. If you add the link to the post you wanted to edit, I can check that (assuming the pending edit hasn't gone through yet - if it has, you can see it too)

Comment: @Zoe This was the question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57769034/9447571 and indeed I do see "Suggest Edit" now! Thanks!

Comment: @Zoe Would you please make this into an answer? It did solve my problem. I also take issue with the error message: "Account not allowed to suggest edits." The problem has nothing to do with the account, but with the question/answer having pending edits already... A more accurate message would have been better here!

Comment: You probably can't edit that question because there's another suggested edit.

Comment: I don't see any suggested edit bans on your account @filbranden... so Zoe's answer as far as I can tell is correct - you're only allowed (on SO at least) at most 5 suggested edits pending at a time. I would say though, please make sure your edits aren't trivial ones and end up rejected for that reason/or another, as that will trigger the system to automatically issue an actual 7 day suggested edit ban.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Suggested edits by other users may hide or just disable the edit button (disable as in when you click it, there's an error). The edit button is also hidden from the mobile layout if there's a pending edit, regardless of how much rep you have.

As for the message, if that's what you got without being banned, it's far from user-friendly. That being said, I suggest you check with another post to verify that you aren't edit banned (but at 4 approved and 2 rejected, it doesn't make sense for an edit ban to be in place).

Given there [is a pending edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23955740) that has been there for about 2 hours, that seems like the reason you were unable to edit.

Comment: Thanks @Zoe! I now see the "Suggest Edit" button again and it seems to work again. In the mobile app, while the question has a pending edit, if I go to "··· More" I do see an "Edit" (not suggest, but really "Edit") and after editing, if I tap "SUGGEST" at the top, I get the error message above. I agree that's not great user experience, therefore the posting here on Meta. Thanks for figuring this one out for me!